# how to undo file permission settings iin filezilla

Tags: ssh, cygwin

I accidentally changed file permission of my .ssh folder and authorized_keys file to 700 on my server using file permission in filezilla. But due to this i can't connect to my server giving this error:
Error:  Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
Error:  Could not connect to server

Please help me out to solve this issue as i cant view my files on filezilla as it is not connected to my server to undo all changes.

Answer (score 0):

> I accidentally changed file permission of my `.ssh` folder and `authorized_keys` file to 700 on my server using file permission in filezilla. But due to this i can't connect to my server giving this error: Error: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey) Error: Could not connect to server

It's not due to file permission 700. Having that permission on `.ssh` and `.ssh/authorized_keys` does not prevent login with keys. This permission is restrictive enough. Permission settings can prevent login with keys if they are too relaxed. So the cause is something different.

It seems the server only allows login with keys.
Make sure that Filezilla indeed uses your keys.
You might need to give it the path to your *private* key file.
For troubleshooting, it can be good idea to try a different tool to connect to the server, for example `ssh` or `sftp`.

If all else fails, you'll need to get assistance by an administrator of the server.

Comment: Hey janos, thank you so much for your reply.but I tried with your solution. I have .pem file already on server. Using putty and puttygen I converted my .pem file to .ppk file I.e private key.and add that key in filezilla add key option. But still it gives same error. Actually before changing this file permission , I was able to access my server files. So cant understand the problem.

Comment: @darshana Have you changed the content of `authorized_keys`?

Comment: I cant copy my public key to authorized_keys because it is not connecting to my server giving permission denied <public key>

Comment: @darshana I know you cannot do that now. I meant if you changed it while you were connected. Because we still don't know the cause. I suspect that is the cause. It seems your settings were correct, and then you broke it. The permission change is not a problem. In any case, it seems to you don't have a good grasp of how to setup authentication with keys in general, and that makes debugging very difficult.

Comment: So is there any way to do so ?

Comment: @darshana I think you need to get assistance by an administrator of the server

Comment: Yes the last option remains the same

Comment: If I asked administrative to send me credentials , what will be the next steps? Sorry I  am totally new to this procedure